# Can I do this vector operation?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product

> Given: [image]

So basically I just need to work with vector operations in order to get the result. In trying to solve this problem, I arrived at this:

$$(\nabla \times \vec{c}T) \cdot d\vec{a}$$
$$=d\vec{a} \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{c}T)$$
$$=(d\vec{a} \times \nabla) \cdot \vec{c}T$$
$$=\vec{c}T \cdot (d\vec{a} \times \nabla)$$

Here's the part I'm wondering about. Am I allowed to distribute the $T$ to only one term of the cross-product? That is,
$$=\vec{c} \cdot (d\vec{a} \times T \nabla)$$

Otherwise, if I'm going completely the wrong way with this problem feel free to let me know.

---

**Another attempt:**

$$(\nabla \times \vec{c}T) \cdot d\vec{a}$$
$$=(T(\nabla \times \vec{c}) - \vec{c} \times (\nabla T)) \cdot d\vec{a}$$
$$=(T(\nabla \times \vec{c}) + \nabla T \times \vec{c}) \cdot d\vec{a}$$
$$=T(\nabla \times \vec{c} + \nabla  \times \vec{c}) \cdot d\vec{a}$$
$$=2T(\nabla \times \vec{c} ) \cdot d\vec{a}$$
$$=(2T\nabla \times \vec{c} ) \cdot d\vec{a}$$
$$=(d\vec{a} \times 2T\nabla) \cdot \vec{c} $$

Right hand side:

$$\vec{c}T \cdot d\vec{l}$$
$$=\vec{c} \cdot Td\vec{l}$$

Putting it all together:

$$\int (d\vec{a} \times 2T\nabla) \cdot \vec{c}   = \oint \vec{c} \cdot Td\vec{l}$$

But now there are some problems:

1. Can I cancel a dot product occurring on both sides even though they are both under an integral sign?
2. The $2$ on the LHS does not appear in the final answer.
3. I can't flip $T \nabla \to \nabla T$ because the former is an operator and the latter is a vector.

Any advice??

Comment: Try $c=(1,0,0)$ and go from there.

Comment: Can I do that if $\vec{c}$ is a vector function?

Comment: You tell me, why could/couldn't you?

Comment: I don't think so because $\vec{c}$ describes a vector field for all points in space.

Comment: Also, understand that there's no $c$ in the final expression, so what I'm doing is looking to substitute something that, in this case, will help recover the RHS.

Comment: And what if my vector field was the constant one, that at all points in space took the value $(1,0,0)$?

Comment: Maybe I phrased it wrong but I assumed "vector function" meant that each point in space is described by a different vector.

Comment: You phrased it just fine. Functions, including vector functions, can be constant. The first identity holds for all smooth vector functions, so you can substitute a constant one. That's the hint. Good luck.

Comment: Using your hint, I got as far as deriving $(0,\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}, -\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}) \cdot d\vec{a}$. Now I need to multiply the vector by $d\vec{a}$, which is the vector normal to the surface. But this normal vector could be in any direction. All I can really say is $(0,\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}, -\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}) \cdot d\vec{a} = (0,da_y\frac{\partial T}{\partial z}, da_z -\frac{\partial T}{\partial y})$.